# std::string == not working?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I do:

```
std::string name = targetBone->getName();
    if(name == "Pelvis")
    {
        return;
    }
```

I get:

`Error  1   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

How do I resolve this error ?

Thanks

Comment: More information is required. Everything is Ok in this example. See http://ideone.com/nHdt2

Comment: Are you using this in a windows environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you included string in your cpp file

```
#include <string>
```

This usually happens because the compiler need to see the definition of string class that resides in that included file to verify that it indeed declares an operator that takes a **char***

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the

```
#include <string>
```

Besides, for comparing strings, you should use [strcmp()](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/c/strcmp) built-in function instead of just using the operator.